# How to code the program in the Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, while-loop, bin

How to code the program in the Shell Script to calculate the sum of the Fibonacci series with the upper limit input from the keyboard? Input for example: "Enter the limit of the Fibonacci series? 10". and the result: 0 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 5 + 8 + 13 + 21 + 34 = 88

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 1 ]
then 
    Num=$1
else
    echo -n "Enter the limits of the Fibonacci sequence : "
    read Num
fi

a=0
b=1

echo "Result : "
for (( i=0;i<=Num;i++ ))
do
    echo -n “$a + “
    n=$((a+b))
    a=$b
    b=$n
done
echo
```

Anyone know how to get the results?
my expected output is:

```
Enter the limits of the Fibonacci sequence : 10
Result : 0 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 5 + 8 + 13 + 21 + 34 = 88
```

I'm stuck trying

Comment: `“` is not `"`. The precise characters used matter.

Comment: Beyond that -- include your _actual_ results in the question, not just your desired results (and unless collecting input is part of the problem, it's better to just hardcode your values so everyone gets the same behavior, instead of guessing at what value of `Num` you used in your test run).

Comment: You already know how to add numbers (`n=$((a+b))`) so why don't you just add each of the numbers to a sum and then `echo` it at the end?

Comment: I just haven't found a pattern for Fibonacci summation, can you help me?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-nth-fibonacci-number/

Comment: wanted to throw in a version. :) `seq=( 0 1 );
read -p "Enter the limits of the Fibonacci sequence : " lim;
while ((${#seq[@]}<lim));do seq+=($((${seq[-2]}+${seq[-1]})) );done;
tot=0;
printf "Result :";
sep='';
for v in "${seq[@]}";do let tot+=v;printf "%s %d " "${sep++}" $v;done;
echo "= $tot"
`

Comment: thanks for adding a different version! but when I run it, it still has syntax errors. its okay, I'll try to fix your code again later ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat fib
#!/bin/bash
Num=${1-5}
a=0
b=1
unset s

printf "Result: "
for (( i=0; i<Num; i++ )); do
    printf "${s:+ + }$a"
    s=$(($s + $a))
    n=$((a+$b))
    a=$b
    b=$n
done
echo " = $s"
$ ./fib 5
Result: 0 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 3 = 7
$ ./fib 10
Result: 0 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 5 + 8 + 13 + 21 + 34 = 88
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
a=1; 
b=0; 
sum=$a; 
for ((i=1;i<10-1;++i)); do 
    ((tmp=b)); 
    ((b=a)); 
    ((a+=tmp)); 
    ((sum+=a)); 
done; 
echo $sum;
```

Output from my terminal:

```
[ichramm@hypernova][Wed, 28 Oct 16:19:24][~]
$ a=1; b=0; sum=$a; for ((i=1;i<10-1;++i)); do ((tmp=b)); ((b=a)); ((a+=tmp)); ((sum+=a)); done; echo $sum;
88
```

Comment: my expected output is:
Enter the limits of the Fibonacci sequence?
then I type 10, and the result is 0 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 5 + 8 + 13 + 21 + 34 = 88.
Btw, thanks for your experiment. You are cool!